# SET WithCredentials globally with axios on VueJS

Tags: vue.js, cookies, axios

In main.js, I put

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

It should work, but by this way the cookies are not sent to the back end.

Here the request header

[image]

If in specific request I add {withCredentials: true}, it's work fine

However, I put an interceptor for all request, to check the options sent,

Do you have an idea not to put in each request this option?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; Please check if axios is not the instance. it should be axios which is imported from node_modules

Comment: I import like this :
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

and my requests like this (inside a vue component)
this.axios.post(myPath)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, I decided to give up axios, and to use vue-resource, I used an interceptor to add credential = true, like this, and it works fine.

In the main.js file :

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request) {
  request.credentials = true
  return function(response) {
  };
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Axios also provide interceptors. You can configure it like this:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.withCredentials = true;
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```